# State array push in vuex is not a function error

Tags: javascript, vue.js, state, vuex, store

I have an array in store/localStorage to save a user's id and work time. However the array.push function is not working.

```
export const state = () => ({
    Total: []
})

export const mutations = {
    setTotal(state, value){
        state.Total.push(value);
    }
}
```

I have this in my created:

```
this.$store.commit("localStorage/setTotal", {id: this.signedInUserID, time: 0});
```

This is the error I got:

**TypeError: state.Total.push is not a function**

Comment: The `"localStorage/"` prefix implies you have a namespaced Vuex module. Did you set that up properly?

Comment: This code is not enough to tell what is wrong

Comment: I have an object call User in state and a setUser function in mutations, which is works properly.

Comment: I am trying to add a new object to my array in state and I got an error: TypeError: state.Total.push is not a function . I will provide any additional code if you want, what would it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your state is a function, which returns an object. You would be able to access `Total` by calling `state` function and then working with the returned object like this:  `state().Total.push(value)`.

However in Vuex you create `store` using `Vuex.Store()`.

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    Total: []
  },
  mutations: {
    setTotal(state, value){
      this.state.Total.push(value);
    }
  }
});
```

If you want to export mutations for testing reasons, you can do so by defining them before and then still assign them in Vuex store.